Cross-sectional analysis combining multiple years of complex survey data
Many large health surveys such as the Survey of Health, Ageing and Retirement in Europe have a longitudinal complex survey design with multiple years of data collection available. I am aware that a multi-year stacked complex survey design object can be used for longitudinal comparisons as described in the following blog post (i.e. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/11/statistically-significant-trends-with-multiple-years-of-complex-survey-data/) which provides this R code as an example:
# construct a complex sample survey design object
# stacking multiple years and accounting for `year` in the nested strata
des <- 
    svydesign(
        id = ~psu , 
        strata = ~interaction( stratum , year ) ,
        data = y , 
        weights = ~weight , 
        nest = TRUE
    )

However, I am curious if the same approach can be applied to cross-sectional research questions. Questions below:
Question 1) General. In general, would it be good practice for researchers to construct a multi-year stacked complex survey design object when interested in researching cross-sectional associations in multi-year panel surveys? I haven’t seen any papers do this, but wouldn’t it increase the statistical power and avoid leaving out available data?
Question 2) Clustering. I assume the argument id = ~psu is sufficient to adjust for the fact that the same participants can be included in multiple years (provided they have the same psu value in each).
Question 3) Weights. I assume the cross-sectional sampling weights of each wave could simply be divided by the number of waves included to retain the correct totals as described here: Combining Multiple Years of Survey Data - Adjusting Survey Weights.
Question 4) Stratification. Is the interaction argument strata = ~interaction( stratum , year ) also appropriate if using the data for cross-sectional associations?


Yes.  For example, the documentation for NHANES says


Each two-year cycle and any combination of two-year cycles is a
nationally representative sample. However, sometimes the size of a
particular sample is too small in an individual two-year cycle to
produce statistically reliable estimates. Fortunately, the NHANES
sample design makes it possible to combine two or more cycles to
increase the sample size and analytic options. This enables the
analyst to produce estimates with greater statistical reliability for
demographic subdomains (e.g. sex – age – race and Hispanic origin
groups) or rare events


Yes, if ~psu is sufficient in a single wave (the US National Center for Health Statistics tends to re-use PSU labels for each stratum, so the combination of stratum and PSU is needed even for a single wave)

Yes. Though for a longer time period you'd need to consider whether you want equal weight for each wave or equal weight for each person (as that link says)

Yes.  Sample sizes will have been prespecified for each (stratum, wave) combination, so those combinations are the correct values for strata


